# How to optimize simple table with groups and timestamps (SUM over 15M rows with GROUP BY)

Tags: mysql, query-performance, index, optimization, aggregate

I think I have quite simple question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.
I'm using MySQL and I have a simple table:

| id | timestamp | groupId | costA | costB | costC | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-01 19:45 | 1 | 5,13 | 3,20 | 30,20 | ... |
| 2 | 2022-02-01 19:45 | 2 | 1,13 | 6,20 | 40,20 | ... |
| 3 | 2022-02-01 19:45 | 3 | 2,13 | 7,20 | 50,20 | ... |
| 4 | 2022-02-01 20:00 | 1 | 12,23 | 13,20 | 20,20 | ... |
| 5 | 2022-02-01 20:00 | 2 | 23,23 | 15,20 | 22,20 | ... |

Some rules of the table:

- timestamp is always the time dividable by 15 minutes.
- for each timestamp there is about 5000 rows,
- there are > 5k groups,
- there are > 5k new rows each 15 minutes, which makes about 500k new rows a day,
- currently I have one index ON (timestamp, groupId).

I want to query that table in two ways:

```
SELECT timestamp, SUM(costA), SUM(costB), SUM(costC) 
FROM table 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :date1 and :date2 
AND groupId IN (:idList)
GROUP BY timestamp
```

which returns:

| timestamp | SUM(costA) | SUM(costB) | SUM(costC) | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-02-01 19:45 | 5,13 | 3,20 | 30,20 | ... |
| 2022-02-01 20:00 | 2,23 | 13,20 | 20,20 | ... |

AND

```
SELECT groupId, SUM(costA), SUM(costB), SUM(costC) 
FROM table 
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :date1 and :date2 
AND groupId IN (:idList)
GROUP BY groupId
```

which returns

| groupId | SUM(costA) | SUM(costB) | SUM(costC) | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5,13 | 3,20 | 30,20 | ... |
| 2 | 2,23 | 13,20 | 20,20 | ... |

To do so - I created an index ON two columns (timestamp, groupId), but when I try to run the query on long date range (for example a month - which makes a sum of 15M rows), the MySQL is either very slow (takes minutes to execute it) or the timeout occurs and select cannot be executed.

I just wonder what I could do to make it really fast, like respond in less than 1 second for a month set. I don't know if the index I have is correct, but when I use "DESCRIBE" it looks like it's using correct index or maybe I should add more memory to the MySQL server?

Comment: Can you please add the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to your post? It should give a picture of what your query is currently doing. Unlikely you have a memory problem, more likely an execution plan problem.

Comment: *`WHERE timestamp BETWEEN :date1 and :date2`* What are the values for the parameters in this conditions? are they clear dates, without the timepart? what is the most common datews range? *`AND groupId IN (:idList)`* Does this groups list looks like random, or some "supergroups" which are used in most cases exists? *and I have a simple table* Provide CREATE TABLE for it.

Comment: Anycase the partitioning (partition by `timestamp` with subpartitioning by `groupId`) looks like a suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
INDEX(groupID, timestamp)
```

It will help some of the cases you presented.

Are your time ranges always full days?  If so, daily subtotals in a summary table would be much faster.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  With that many rows, let's discuss the datatypes.  And if you have an `id` whether you can get rid of it -- and promote one of the indexes to be the PK.

How long does the insert of 5K rows take?  If needed, we can discuss improvements on that.

Since you have a 2-dimensional index, it may be worth discussing PARTITIONing.  But first, will you be deleting "old" rows?  If yes, then I will definitely push for `PARTITION BY RANGE TO_ROWS(..)`.  How much data will be kept (eg, "one year's worth")?  How many different "groups"?

How much RAM?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?